# JodaTime get beginning of tomorrow

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to find an optimal way to convert a DateTime to the beginning of tomorrow.

Right now, I have:

```
DateTime bar = foo.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

But this creates at least 3 objects -- 2 DateTimes and a local date.

The equivalent that creates only the DateTime I need seems to be this:

```
long tomorrow = foo.getChronology().days().add(foo.getMillis(), 1);
tomorrow = foo.getChronology().dayOfMonth().roundFloor(tomorrow);
DateTime bar = foo.withMillis(tomorrow);
```

But I'm not sure if this will account for DST and other transitions properly.

Comment: What do you mean with "this creates at least 3 objects"? Afaik Jodatime Objects are immutable, that means every change creates a new object. But the older objects won't be kept unless you do that manually

Comment: The older objects are lost yes, I'm just trying to avoid creating them to begin with. I could do MutableDateTime objs but then I have to convert the DateTime to be mutable to begin with.

Comment: Have you actually measured performance and found that you have a problem? If not, I **strongly** urge you not to sacrifice simplicity for the sake of unproven performance.

Comment: But why do you want to do that? Immutable Objects are a nice practice and Jodatime ist designed to do it this way.

Comment: @JonSkeet that's the tradeoff I've been considering, at this point my loop iterations are fast enough that the conversion is actually noticeable

Comment: @rollback I agree, I was just curious if there was some better way that isn't a hack.

Comment: @SameerPuri: What does your loop do, exactly? Is there a way of moving some of this logic out of the loop? Even if it's noticeable at the level of your loop, is it significant to your overall application performance?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm polling an external rest API for data. It's not a big part of the overall performance, just something I could optimize